# How to get particular labels and entities from HTML content as concatenated string?

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```html
<div id="formContents" class="dformDisplay "><div class="sectionDiv expanded">
    <div class="Title expanded ToggleSection shead" id="sect_s1Header" style="margin-top:1em">
    <span class="sectionTitle">Issue details:</span></div>
    <hr/>
    <div><!--The div around the table is so that the toggling can be animated smoothly-->
    <table class="formSection LabelsAbove" id="sect_s1">
    <tr class="formRow">
    <td class="label lc" id="tdl_8">
    <label class="fieldLabel"><b>Address</b></label>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="EmailFieldPadder" style="width:98%;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:1.5em;" valign="top">
    <tr><td class="EmailDivWrapper" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;padding: 0.83em;border-radius:3px;margin:0;border:0px;">
    <div class="cell cc" id="tdf_8">
    <a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=1183+Pelham+Wood+Dr%2C+Rock+Hill%2C+SC+29732">1183
    Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732</a>
    </div>
    </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    <td class="label lc" colspan="100" id="tdl_9">
    <label class="fieldLabel"><b>Dispatch Region</b></label>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="EmailFieldPadder" style="width:98%;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:1.5em;" valign="top">
    <tr><td class="EmailDivWrapper" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;padding: 0.83em;border-radius:3px;margin:0;border:0px;">
    <div class="cell cc nowrap" id="tdf_9">5</div>
    </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="formRow">
    <td class="label lc" id="tdl_10">
    <label class="fieldLabel"><b>Market:</b></label>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="EmailFieldPadder" style="width:98%;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:1.5em;" valign="top">
    <tr><td class="EmailDivWrapper" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;padding: 0.83em;border-radius:3px;margin:0;border:0px;">
    <div class="cell cc" id="tdf_10">Charlotte</div>
    </td></tr></table>
    </td>
    <div class="sectionDiv expanded">
    <div class="Title expanded ToggleSection shead"
      style="margin-top:1em"
     id="sect_s19Header">
    <span class="sectionTitle">Tenant Preferred Scheduled Date/Time</span></div>
    <hr />
    <div><!--The div around the table is so that the toggling can be animated smoothly-->
    <table id="sect_s19" class="formSection LabelsLeft">
    
    <tr class="formRow ">
    <td id="tdl_52" class="label lc"
    
         style="vertical-align:top; border:0 solid white; border-bottom-width: .83em; padding: 0.83em 0; border-right-width: .83em;"
    
    ><label class="fieldLabel" ><b>Preference 1: </b></label></td>
    <td id="tdf_52"  class="cell cc nowrap"
    
         style="background-color:#f5f5f5; border: solid white; border-top-width:0;border-right-width: 5.455em; border-left-width:.909em; vertical-align:top; border-bottom-width: .909em; padding: .83em;"
    
     >Friday, 02-03</td>
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
section_sel = 'div#formContents div.sectionDiv.expanded'
label_sel = 'label.fieldLabel'
for datas in soup.select(f'{section_sel}:has({label_sel}+table td)'):
    labels = datas.select(f'{label_sel}:has(+table td)')
    labels = [' '.join(l.get_text(' ').split()) for l in labels]
    entity_data = [' '.join([' '.join(td.get_text(' ').split()) for td in ed.select('td')]) for ed in datas.select(f'{label_sel}+table:has(td)')]
    for l, ed in zip(labels, entity_data): print(f'{l}: {ed}')
```

Required output: Address: 1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732 ; Dispatch Region: 5 ; Market: Charlotte ; Preference 1: Friday, 02-03

I am unable to get the Preference 1 with the solution. I am getting all other label. Since there is no table tag below label tag its not getting. Kindly help with solution to get all labels from the html content

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<hr>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-hr-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75418536/14460824) and use `dict` to create a CSV, what I assume you like to prepare with the string construct.

However, use the approache and this way:

```
';'.join(
    [
        f"{e.text.strip(': ')}:{' '.join(e.find_next('td').text.split())}" 
        for e in soup.select('div#formContents label')
    ]
)
```

What results into:

```
'Address:1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732;Dispatch Region:5;Market:Charlotte;Preference 1:Friday, 02-03'
```

Comment: how to replace this code in my code.. Is it entity_data I have to replace

Comment: It would replace all of your selections and logic, use it directly after creating your `soup`.